# Is it possible to create a RAID 1 Array with only one disk and add the second later?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas

I just bought my first **NAS** with two bays. Next thing which are missing are the hard disks. I wanted to buy **WD RED 4TB WD40EFRX** but these things are so expensive, that I could only afford one of them for now.

Is it possible to create a RAID 1 System with only one disk and add the second one later, so the data of disk 0 is automatically copied to disk 1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays some NAS software allow you to migrate the system from single disk to RAID 1, RAID 5, RAID 6 or RAID 10 (if you have enough bays, obviously).

QNAS Turbo: http://docs.qnap.com/nas/4.1/Home/en/index.html?raid_management.htm

Sylonogy: https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/volume_diskgroup_change_raid_type